# How to open same(pdf) document in two different tabs in foxit reader?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader, foxit-reader

I am trying to open the same document in two tabs of Foxit reader, but I don't know how to do it. 
What I did or what I want to do :

1. I just open one PDF with Foxit reader.
2. Same file: I want to open it in the same instance of Foxit, but in a different tab.

But If I open same PDF again, in any way, it comes to the same tab in that same file was open.

Comment: Hi welcome to SuperUser. Can you [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1015277/edit) your question to explain what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've tried [this answer from the Foxit forum](https://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-reader/615-is-it-possible-to-open-the-same-document-in-two-tabs), and it works with Foxit reader v9.7

> I have found a way to open multiple instances of the same PDF in different tabs:

1. Open the desired PDF.
2. Go to File
3. Under 'recent documents', right-click on the PDF and select 'Open a copy'.

A copy of the PDF should now have been opened in a different tab.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this function is not supported in Foxit Reader. I would recommend making a copy of your file and then opening that copy in a separate tab.

Comment: Well features like 1- multiple-tabs of the same document and 2- a nice dark-mode are good ideas to add in the software (I take it as you are in the team of devs...)

Answer (score 2):

Two methods:

1. Open the PDF document with Foxit Reader

   > Go to "View" -> click on "Split", then you'll see the same PDF document been displayed separately in one PDF window.
2. Go to

   > File -> Preference -> Documents "open setting" -> check box "Allow multiple instances"-> ok

   then open Foxit reader->open and "choose your same pdf"